# how php form id works, is my mapping is right?

Tags: php

I have created an php page with 2 forms and its respective form id

```
<form id="form1" action="controller.php" method="post">
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
<input name="act" type="submit" value="adding" />
<!-- form1. -->
</form>
<form id="form2" action="controller.php" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
<input name="act" type="submit" value="editing" />
<!-- form2. -->
</form>
```

And it redirects to another php form when submitted

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['act']))
{
    if($_POST['act']=='form1')
    {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $date=date('y-m-d');
        $query="insert into identity(name,email,password,post_date) values((''),('$email'),(''),('$date'));";
        $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($run)
        {
            echo "<h3><center>email inserted</center></h3>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h3><center>not done</center></h3>";
        }
        header("Location:formtest.php");
    }
    else if($_POST['act']=='form2')
    {
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $date=date('y-m-d');
        $query="insert into identity(name,email,password,post_date) values(('$name'),(''),(''),('$date'))";
        $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($run)
        {
            echo "<h3><center>name inserted</center></h3>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h3><center>not done for name</h3></center>";
        }
        header("Location:formtest.php");    
    }
}
?>
```

But unable to submit form with their respective ID, it's stuck at redirect page and does not insert any data in Mysql database !

Comment: Ids are not passed to server. `Print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Have you used that SQL directly on the DB before? Where does the request go currently? You also are open to SQL injections and should be hashing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

To identify a form, you have two options:

1. Read the name of the submit button
2. Add a hidden field with a name and value, and read that.

The "name" of a form is not passed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what you are asking about IDs, but it is quite clear that you are checking for  wrong values here:

```
if($_POST['act']=='form1')
```

and here:

```
if($_POST['act']=='form2')
```

as in your form the values ar respectively:

```
<input name="act" type="submit" value="adding" />
```

and

```
<input name="act" type="submit" value="editing" />
```

Try to fix it this way:

```
if($_POST['act']=='adding')
if($_POST['act']=='editing')
```

and  your code will executes correctly.

Comment: I need to map the entire form with id not the submit button, and call it in controller.php(redirect page) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the form ids as hidden variables, like

```
<form id="form1" action="controller.php" method="post">
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
<input name="act" type="submit" value="adding" />
<input name="formid" type="hidden" value="1" />
<!-- form1. -->
</form>
<form id="form2" action="controller.php" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
<input name="act" type="submit" value="editing" />
<input name="formid" type="hidden" value="2" />
<!-- form2. -->
</form>
```

Comment: I need to map the entire form with id not with another hidden field?